UPS Steppingstone Endpoints. Login with SOAP/XML
I have this code that worked all the time.
How to create a class now to send this token?
 FauthData := uUPSShip_WSDL.UPSSecurity.Create;
  userToken:= uUPSShip_WSDL.UsernameToken.Create;
  userToken.Username:=..........;
  userToken.Password :=............;
  FauthData.UsernameToken:= userToken;
  serviceToken:= uUPSShip_WSDL.ServiceAccessToken.Create;
  serviceToken.AccessLicenseNumber :=..............;
  FauthData.ServiceAccessToken:= serviceToken;
  request_:= ShipmentRequest.Create;

 (FiServices as ISOAPHeaders).send(FauthData);

ProcessShipment(request_, nil);
I wanted to replace the existing authorization data with the class:
Authorization = class(TSOAPHeader)
private
 FBearer:string;

public
published
 property Bearer:string read FBearer write FBearer;

end;
under property Bearer I provide the Oauth2 token  "Bearer ..........". And its not working
I have an error:
err:Code250002</err:Code>
err:DescriptionInvalid Authentication Information.</err:Description>
What is wrong ?
Does anyone know what this authorization class should look like? UPS is very frugal when it comes to documentation
Its not working too 

We do it like this:
var
  Request: ShipmentRequest;
  ShipChargeArray: Array_Of_ShipmentChargeType;
  Shipcharge: ShipmentChargeType;
  RefNumberArray: Array_Of_ReferenceNumberType;
  RefNumber: ReferenceNumberType;
  PackageArray: Array_Of_PackageType;
  Package: PackageType;
  Security: UPSSecurity;
  Response: ShipmentResponse;
  ShipService: ShipPortType;
begin
...
  Request := ShipmentRequest.Create;
  Try
    Request.Request := UPSAPIU.Request.Create;
    Security := UPSSecurity.Create;

... // lots of other field assignemnts

    Security.UsernameToken := UserNameToken.Create;
    Security.UsernameToken.Username := GetFieldValue('UPS_BenutzerName');
    Security.UsernameToken.Password := GetFieldValue('UPS_Password');

    Security.ServiceAccessToken := ServiceAccessToken.Create;
    Security.ServiceAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber := GetFieldValue('UPS_AccessLicencenr');

    ShipService := GetShipService;
    try
      (ShipService as ISOAPHeaders).Send(Security);
      Response := ShipService.ProcessShipment(request, nil);
    except
      on E: Exception do begin
        LogError(...); // internal error logging
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  Finally
    Security.Free;
    request.Free;
    if Assigned(response) then
      response.Free;
  End;
...
end;

and the consumed WSDL(s):
since it's too long for a direct paste, you get it via this link:
https://gist.github.com/zaffinger/ab83bc213ed567b2f7fa80d74f2f56e5
